# Laravel route conflict with resource routes

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using this route in a project hosted in my local mac pc, it is working, but when i have uploaded that to an `Ubunto` server route conflict occurred.

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'report', 'middleware' => ['auth','session', 'complete_profile']], function() {
    Route::get('/get_query', 'ReportController@get_queries');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','session', 'complete_profile']], function(){
    Route::resource('report','ReportController');
});
```

for example when i use form first route `report/get_query` in online `ubunto` server it goes to the `show($id)` method of that controller, But in local its working.
What should I do with this ?

Comment: Did you try putting the first Route group after the resource route?

Comment: @prateekkathal I have tested that, but on that time conflict occur on my local mac

Comment: Please note that in Ubuntu, everything is case sensitive. Even index.Php and index.php would make a huge difference. Check if you maybe have any upper and lower case mistakes. Happened to me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'report', 'middleware' => ['auth','session', 'complete_profile']], function() {
    Route::resource('/','ReportController',['except' => ['show']]);
    Route::get('/get_query', 'ReportController@get_queries');
});
```

Resource route has predefined route for http methodes. For example reporte resource has route:

```
Route::get('report/{report}','ReportController@show');
```

Solution is to exclude some methodes (routes from restfull resource), or to make some routes that wont conflict with route resource.

You can see what route you have registered by running:

```
 php artisan route:list
```

Also one route group for report is enough just put '/' in resource route.